# More complex associative arrays in QT

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, qt4

Hi everybody and thanks for your time,

I read filenames in a QList. This is what I've done:

```
QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
if(dialog.exec()) {
    files.append(dialog.selectedFiles());
}
foreach(QString file, files) {
    // add files to a table
}
```

I have all files in the QList files. Now I want the user to add information to this list. In PHP (or javascript) I would do something like this:

```
$fileinformation = array();
foreach($files AS $file) {
    array_push($fileinformation, array (
                                       'filename'   => $file,
                                       'doAction1'  => false,
                                       'doAction2'  => true,
                                       'parameter2' => array (
                                                              'value1' => $val1,
                                                              'value2' => $val2
                                                       )
                                       )
    )
}
```

And in the next step, I would make it possible for the user to edit the default options by editing `$fileinformation['parameter2']['value']`. But how can I do this in QT? I know, there are certain functions in qt like QList and QMap but both are not multidimensional and too unflexible for this case.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't missed anything. In a statically-typed language, you generally do not have objects of a completely different type all in the same container.

Assuming all of the parameters are defined at compile time, you can define a class or struct that contains those parameters and store it in a list. For brevity, I'm using a raw struct in this example. You may wish to explicitly initialize its members with a constructor and possibly wrap its data into a meaningful class.

```
struct FileInformation
{
   QString filename;
   bool doAction1;
   bool doAction2;

   struct ParameterStruct
   {
      QString value1; // I'm guessing it's QString, since you don't show what type it was.
      QString value2;
   } parameter2;
};

int main()
{
   QList<FileInformation> myList;
   FileInformation info;
   info.fileName = "filename.txt";
   info.doAction1 = false;
   info.doAction2 = true;
   info.parameter2.value1 = "someValue";
   info.parameter2.value2 = "someOtherValue";
   myList.append(info);

   //now to change stuff!
   myList[0].parameter2.value1 = "a new value";
}
```

It is possible to do this more akin to your example above (by nesting QVariantMaps), but that would be quite ugly, as C++'s static typing would demand manually casting at every access.

Comment: How ugly. * *gg* * I will try this! Thank you!

Comment: As a note, you may want to have someone familiar with C++ and Qt review your code when you're done. If you're new to C++, there's a lot of pitfalls. There is a code review stack exchange, which might be of help.